# Issue with xml.etree.ElementTree while writing GeoPandas nodes data into OSM format

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopandas, xml, nodes

I have sample nodes data like below. I am writing geopandas into osm data using `xml.etree.ElementTree` but the end output is not matching the nodes format that is described in osm data. Actually at every end of node it has to write `</nodes>` which the library `xml.etree.ElementTree` is not writing. Is it the problem with the `xml.etree.ElementTree` or am I writing it wrong?

What is the best library to use to write GeoPandas to OSM data?

nodes:-

```
     id           lon         lat          geometry
0   556223075   -2.713297   51.591859   POINT (-2.71330 51.59186)
1   6727779 -2.714531   51.591813   POINT (-2.71453 51.59181)
2   556223881   -2.714350   51.591444   POINT (-2.71435 51.59144)
3   6727771 -2.716362   51.590964   POINT (-2.71636 51.59096)
4   6727772 -2.716803   51.591356   POINT (-2.71680 51.59136)
5   6727773 -2.717246   51.591788   POINT (-2.71725 51.59179)
6   6727795 -2.718631   51.590466   POINT (-2.71863 51.59047)
7   10303754878 -2.718294   51.590546   POINT (-2.71829 51.59055)
```

code:-

```
osm = ET.Element("osm", {"version": "0.6", "generator": "Python"})
for idx, row in n_gdf.iterrows():
    node = ET.SubElement(osm, "node", {"id": str(row["id"]), "lat": str(row["lat"]), "lon": str(row["lon"])})
tree = ET.ElementTree(osm)
tree.write(path, encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

output:-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Python"><node id="556223075" lat="51.5918587" lon="-2.7132966" />
<node id="6727779" lat="51.5918134" lon="-2.7145312" />
<node id="556223881" lat="51.5914444" lon="-2.7143497" /><node id="6727771" lat="51.5909638" lon="-2.7163618" />
<node id="6727772" lat="51.5913561" lon="-2.7168026" /><node id="6727773" lat="51.5917876" lon="-2.7172457" /><node id="6727795" lat="51.5904663" lon="-2.7186308" />

<node id="10303754878" lat="51.5905456" lon="-2.7182938" /></osm>
```

Execpted output:-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Python"><node id="556223075" lat="51.5918587" lon="-2.7132966" /> </node>
<node id="6727779" lat="51.5918134" lon="-2.7145312" /></node>
<node id="556223881" lat="51.5914444" lon="-2.7143497" /></node>
<node id="6727771" lat="51.5909638" lon="-2.7163618" /></node>
<node id="6727772" lat="51.5913561" lon="-2.7168026" /></node>
<node id="6727773" lat="51.5917876" lon="-2.7172457" /></node>
<node id="6727795" lat="51.5904663" lon="-2.7186308" /></node>

<node id="10303754878" lat="51.5905456" lon="-2.7182938" /></node></osm>
```

Comment: Why does it matter? They're functionally equivalent.

Comment: https://github.com/roelderickx/ogr2osm